# How can I find the offset of a particular document in a SOLR Query without iteration?

Tags: solr

I have a solr query that looks like this ?q=*:*&fq=section:10&sort=modified_date+desc&start=0&rows=50
 and for example it has 1000000 results.  I also know for a fact that a document exists in the overall result set.  What I don't know is where it exists, for example is it number 325000 out of 1000000 results

Is there a way to determine what location the document exists inside the given query without iterating through the very large result set?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly know some other info about that document right, that is also in some other field indexed in solr, can't you add more conditions (q or fq) to narrow down the result set?

Otherwise I don't think there is a way to help you to find a given doc among all hits without iterating.

Comment: Yes I know everything about the document.  The modified_date, section, and id.  Essentially I am showing a user a list of documents associated with their account read from the db.  I want to inform them that their document appears on a certain page of front end search results.  I was thinking of doing a facet search on the modified_date in order to get the number of documents before it, but it won't be exactly accurate.

Comment: I think i solved my own question.  I'll just retrieve row count of all documents less than the modified_date of the current document and that should be good enough.